# MVC 4 Wonders about running adv at a specific time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a school project building a Ecommerce website. I want to put the adv at a specific time. For instance, I want a adv to be appeared on 2014-12-21 21:00:00, and the adv is supposed to show up automatically on the website. But I'm not sure how it functions. Can you please explain me the way it works or how to do it.
So far I've made up the C# codes for automatically doing something at a specific time.
Thank you for your help!

```
Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time)).Wait();
        dosomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think a better way (without being too loud) should be to check the date every request and show when the date is passed.

So in DB we can inagine a table "Advert" that store all adverts you want with id, name, content of the advert (text? link? path to picture? and BeginDate ...)

```
List<Advert> advertsToShow = yourDB.GetAllAdvert.Where( x=> x.BeginDate > DateTime?Now).toList();
```